# How to restrict the upper limit of rows while doing join in SQL?

Tags: sql, join, greenplum

I have two tables: balance and calendar.

Balance :

```
Account Date        Balance 
1111    01/01/2014  100 
1111    02/01/2014  156 
1111    03/01/2014  300 
1111    04/01/2014  300 
1111    07/01/2014  468

1112    02/01/2014  300
1112    03/01/2014  300
1112    06/01/2014  300
1112    07/01/2014  350
1112    08/01/2014  400
1112    09/01/2014  450

1113    01/01/2014  30
1113    02/01/2014  40
1113    03/01/2014  45
1113    06/01/2014  45
1113    07/01/2014  60
1113    08/01/2014  50
1113    09/01/2014  20
1113    10/01/2014  10
```

Calendar

```
date        business_day_ind
01/01/2014  N
02/01/2014  Y
03/01/2014  Y
04/01/2014  N
05/01/2014  N
06/01/2014  Y
07/01/2014  Y
08/01/2014  Y
09/01/2014  Y
10/01/2014  Y
```

I need to do the following:

- I need to fill in the missing days for all the accounts up to the maximum day for which it has value. Say for account 1111, it has value only till  07/01/2014, so the dates need to be filled only till that. But when I join with the calendar table (plain left join), I am not able restrict the maximum day to the day available for an account.

```
1111   01/01/2014  100 N 
1111   02/01/2014  156 Y 
1111   03/01/2014  300 Y
1111   04/01/2014  300 Y
1111   05/01/2014      N
1111   06/01/2014      N
1111   07/01/2014  468 Y
1111   08/01/2014      Y
1111   09/01/2014      Y
1111   10/01/2014      Y

1112   01/01/2014      N
1112   02/01/2014 300  Y
1112   03/01/2014 300  Y
1112   04/01/2014      N
1112   05/01/2014      N
1112   06/01/2014 300  Y
1112   07/01/2014 350  Y
1112   08/01/2014 400  Y
1112   09/01/2014 450  Y
1112   10/01/2014      Y
```

**I need an efficient way (preferably not involving multiple steps) to restrict the dates up to an account's maximum balance available date (07/01/2014 in case of 1111,09/01/2014 in case 1112)**

Desired output:

```
1111   01/01/2014  100 N 
1111   02/01/2014  156 Y 
1111   03/01/2014  300 Y
1111   04/01/2014  300 Y
1111   05/01/2014      N
1111   06/01/2014      N
1111   07/01/2014  468 Y

1112   01/01/2014      N
1112   02/01/2014 300  Y
1112   03/01/2014 300  Y
1112   04/01/2014      N
1112   05/01/2014      N
1112   06/01/2014 300  Y
1112   07/01/2014 350  Y
1112   08/01/2014 400  Y
1112   09/01/2014 450  Y
```

After filling the missing days, I am planning to impute the balance of previous business day to the missing days. I am planning to get previous business day for every date and do an update to missing rows by joining the original balance table with acct and previous business day as key.

Thanks.

I am Greenplum database.

Comment: Can you add the desired output? It's getting a bit confusing!

Comment: I have added it.

Answer (score 0):

A possible way would be put a second select in a subquery. For instance:

```
select ... from   calendar  a  left outer join balance b on a.date  = b.date 
where a.date <= (select max(date) from balance c where b.Account = c.Account )
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you have third table, `accounts`:

```
select
  accounts.account,
  calendar.date,
  balance.balance,
  calendar.business_day_ind
from
  accounts cross join lateral (
    select * 
    from calendar
    where calendar.date <= (
      select max(date)
      from balance
      where balance.account = accounts.account)) as calendar left join
  balance on (balance.account = accounts.account and balance.date = calendar.date)
order by
  accounts.account, calendar.date;
```

[About lateral joins](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL)

Answer (score 0):

That was a fun challenge!

```
CREATE TABLE balance 
(account int, balance_date timestamp, balance int)
DISTRIBUTED BY (account, balance_date);

INSERT INTO balance 
values (1111,'01/01/2014', 100),
(1111, '02/01/2014', 156),
(1111, '03/01/2014', 300), 
(1111, '04/01/2014', 300),
(1111, '07/01/2014', 468),
(1112, '02/01/2014', 300),
(1112, '03/01/2014', 300),
(1112, '06/01/2014', 300),
(1112, '07/01/2014', 350),
(1112, '08/01/2014', 400),
(1112, '09/01/2014', 450),
(1113, '01/01/2014', 30),
(1113, '02/01/2014', 40),
(1113, '03/01/2014', 45),
(1113, '06/01/2014', 45),
(1113, '07/01/2014', 60),
(1113, '08/01/2014', 50),
(1113, '09/01/2014', 20),
(1113, '10/01/2014', 10);

CREATE TABLE calendar
(calendar_date timestamp, business_day_ind boolean)
DISTRIBUTED BY (calendar_date);

INSERT INTO calendar
values ('01/01/2014', false),
('02/01/2014', true),
('03/01/2014', true),
('04/01/2014', false),
('05/01/2014', false),
('06/01/2014', true),
('07/01/2014', true),
('08/01/2014', true),
('09/01/2014', true),
('10/01/2014', true);

analyze balance;
analyze calendar;
```

And now the query.

```
select d.account, d.my_date, b.balance, c.business_day_ind
from    (
    select account, start_date + interval '1 month' * (generate_series(0, duration)) AS my_date
    from    (
        select account, start_date, (date_part('year', duration) * 12 + date_part('month', duration))::int as duration
        from    (
            select start_date, age(end_date, start_date) as duration, account
            from    (
                select account, min(balance_date) as start_date, max(balance_date) as end_date
                from balance
                group by account
                ) as sub1
            ) as sub2
        ) sub3
    ) as d
left outer join balance b on d.account = b.account and d.my_date = b.balance_date
join calendar c on c.calendar_date = d.my_date
order by d.account, d.my_date;
```

Results:

```
 account |       my_date       | balance | business_day_ind 
---------+---------------------+---------+------------------
    1111 | 2014-01-01 00:00:00 |     100 | f
    1111 | 2014-02-01 00:00:00 |     156 | t
    1111 | 2014-03-01 00:00:00 |     300 | t
    1111 | 2014-04-01 00:00:00 |     300 | f
    1111 | 2014-05-01 00:00:00 |         | f
    1111 | 2014-06-01 00:00:00 |         | t
    1111 | 2014-07-01 00:00:00 |     468 | t
    1112 | 2014-02-01 00:00:00 |     300 | t
    1112 | 2014-03-01 00:00:00 |     300 | t
    1112 | 2014-04-01 00:00:00 |         | f
    1112 | 2014-05-01 00:00:00 |         | f
    1112 | 2014-06-01 00:00:00 |     300 | t
    1112 | 2014-07-01 00:00:00 |     350 | t
    1112 | 2014-08-01 00:00:00 |     400 | t
    1112 | 2014-09-01 00:00:00 |     450 | t
    1113 | 2014-01-01 00:00:00 |      30 | f
    1113 | 2014-02-01 00:00:00 |      40 | t
    1113 | 2014-03-01 00:00:00 |      45 | t
    1113 | 2014-04-01 00:00:00 |         | f
    1113 | 2014-05-01 00:00:00 |         | f
    1113 | 2014-06-01 00:00:00 |      45 | t
    1113 | 2014-07-01 00:00:00 |      60 | t
    1113 | 2014-08-01 00:00:00 |      50 | t
    1113 | 2014-09-01 00:00:00 |      20 | t
    1113 | 2014-10-01 00:00:00 |      10 | t
(25 rows)
```

I had to get the min and max dates for each account and then use generate_series to generate the months between the two dates.  It would have been a bit cleaner query if you wanted a record for each day but I had to use another subquery to get the results at a monthly level.